# News Component Requirement

Tags: aem

We have a requirement to create a News Component. So there will be news pages which we will author contains Title, Image & description. I will store this under one node say content\myproject\newsnode\news1,news2 like this.

On the homepage, I want to show the latest 3 authored news description. For that, I'm thinking of using a news component.
I thought of creating 2 component and map them. Thinking of using the Query builder to fetch the latest news to show on homepage. One component of news page and one component on a homepage to show latest 3 news with Title, Tile image and a small description.

Is there any other approach to this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a dispatcher, querybuilder servlet is blocked by default and should be blocked for obvious reasons.

Since your question is general, I will try to answer generally and on a high level.

There are two possible options I can think of:

**1.** make a servlet to retrieve the last 3 news component information and expose them as JSON. Then send an AJAX request from your browser and change the view accordingly with jquery or your front-end framework of choice.

**Advantages**: No caching, you'll always get the latest news.

**Disadvantages**: SEO, if you care about that in this case. Search engines will 
not index the news on the page since they are not part of the initial markup (not server-side rendered)

**2.** Create a service to get the last 3 news component info then render them on your component via HTL or JSP. Basically server-side render them.

**Advantages**: SEO, same as the reason above.

**Disadvantages**: You have to invalidate the cache for your page every time a new news component is added to make sure your end users get the latest.

Hope this helps.